# Controlling the display in the hexbin plot

Tags: r

I used the following code to generate the attached plot. But how can I control the two distances:
1)  the distance between the main plot on the left and legend on the right ( I marked this distance with double arrow line ). I would like to make this distance shorter.
2) the current x-axis label is so close to the lower border line of the plot.I would like to make this x-axis label lower. Similarly, I would like to move the y-axis label to the left.

```
par(mar=c(10,10,1,0),mgp=c(10,1,0))
plot(matrix.3.numeric.hexbin)
```

Here the matrix.3.numeric.hexbin is a hexbin object. It looks to me whatever I change the parameter in par, the generated plot is always the same.

[image]

Comment: Right. `par` only affects base graphics coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to mix two completely different plotting paradigms. Despite appearing to be a base graphics function, `plot`, the hexbin-plot method is actually a grid-based plotting function. Furthermore it's an S4 method which means you need to use `showMethods` to actually see it. ( I cannot tell if your `par` had any effect or not. (It didn't affect the example I used.)

```
showMethods('plot', class="hexbin", includeDefs=TRUE)
```

This is the argument list:

```
.local <- function (x, style = "colorscale", legend = 1.2, 
    lcex = 1, minarea = 0.04, maxarea = 0.8, mincnt = 1, 
    maxcnt = max(x@count), trans = NULL, inv = NULL, colorcut = seq(0, 
        1, length = min(17, maxcnt)), border = NULL, density = NULL, 
    pen = NULL, colramp = function(n) LinGray(n, beg = 90, 
        end = 15), xlab = NULL, ylab = NULL, main = "", newpage = TRUE, 
    type = c("p", "l", "n"), xaxt = c("s", "n"), yaxt = c("s", 
        "n"), clip = "on", verbose = getOption("verbose"))
```

If you wanted to modify its layout you should be working with what is returned as a value:

```
 plot.vp    the hexViewport constructed and used.
 legend.vp  if a legend has been produced, its viewport.
```

If you look at the code it appears that it will accept an argument "legend" which is the width of the legend viewport in inches, so try modifying that:

```
 plot(bin, legend=1.0)
```

By the way; the confusion about ggplot comes from one of  the plotting methods being named gplot.hexbin, but that "g" is a reference to "grid" rather than to "ggplot"

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're looking for this... although I used [hexbinplot](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/hexbin/docs/hexbinplot):
You can control the displacement of the legend via the viewport (**vp**) argument, like this:

```
require(lattice)
require(hexbin)

some.plot = hexbinplot(d.frame$X ~ d.frame$Y
#   ,par.settings = list(fontsize=list(text=16))
   ,aspect=...,cex.lab=...,xbins=...
   ,vp = viewport(x=0.3,y=0.5,default.units='npc',angle=0,height=0.9)
   ,etc...)
```

all other spacing (even further legend space to right) can be controlled by the settings "embedded" in [lattice](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lattice/index.html) graphs. I used them like this (but I assume you can directly set them up in the "**par.settings**" argument:

```
up.image = update(some.plot,par.settings = list(
   layout.widths=list(left.padding = 0,right.padding = 0
      ,key.ylab.padding = 0,ylab.axis.padding = 0
      ,ylab.right = 0,axis.key.padding = 0)
   ,layout.heights=list(top.padding = 0,bottom.padding = 0
      ,main.key.padding = 0,key.axis.padding = 0
      ,axis.xlab.padding = 0,xlab.key.padding = 0
      ,key.sub.padding = 0)
   ))
```

The idea came from: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2011-August/012612.html

Cheers!