# hexbin: manipulating tick marks and labels

Tags: r, plot, binning

I need to customize axis tick marks and tick labels of hexbin plot:

Hexbinning data which best are transformed prior to binning:

```
library(hexbin)
set.seed(25)
df<-data.frame(x=(rnorm(10000, mean=10, sd=1))^2,y=(rnorm(10000, mean=10, sd=1))^2)
hbo <- hexbin(sqrt(df))
```

The according plot would then be

```
plot(hbo,legend=FALSE,xlab="sqrt(x)",ylab="sqrt(y)",main="Transformed data")
```

I want to backtransform axis tick labels, so that annoying `... ,xlab="sqrt(x)",ylab="sqrt(y)", ...` could then be "x" and "y" again.

For base grafics derived plots, one might suppress the axis (x-axis only here) by

```
plot(hbo,legend=FALSE,main="Quasi-backtranformed data",xaxt="n")
```

and then issue

```
axis(side=1,at=seq(6,14,2),labels=seq(6,14,2)^2)
```

to recreate the respective axis with backtransformed labels.

But this does *NOT* work. It does nothing. The hexbin plot method does indeed not honor most `par` arguments from generic plotting as assumed by [@BondedDust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534823/controlling-the-display-in-the-hexbin-plot). 
Then, hexbin docs say it uses the grid-package for plotting. Having not worked with grid, I didn't do that good so far and I feel like a total doof.

```
library(grid)
grid.xaxis(at = seq(6,14,2), vp = viewport(w = .5, h = 0.01), name = "gxa")
```

again is unresponsive (please don't yell at me).

Above that, axis labels of plot(hexbin-objects) usually overlap with ticklabels, so I would be grateful for a non-Illustrator based method to create fancy hexbin-plots.

Advice on hexbin::tick_mark_and_tick_label_manipulation is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you might be better off with `geom_hexbin()` from the `ggplot2` package ...

Comment: thanks @BenBolker. I need to further analyse the bin-counts (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27155373/hexbin-how-to-trace-bin-contents), so I need something like the hexbin-object. Without looking at ggplot2, it may suck to reproduce hexbin::hexbin with ggplot2. But I'll look into that.

Comment: @Jan, Please note that you may extract the binned data from a `ggplot` object using `ggplot_build`. Something like `p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_hex()`; `ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]`